# Find the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan6x)}{\sin3x}$ without using L'hopital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to compute the following limit: $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan6x}{\sin3x}$$

I really have no idea how to start it. I tried rewriting $\tan6x$ in terms of $\sin6x$ and $\cos6x$ but wasn't able to simplify the expression. How do I go about this?

Comment: Use $\sin 6x=2\sin 3x\cos 3x$.

Comment: In this particular case trigonometric manipulation is fine and maybe the simpler method. For more general cases keep in mind the use of standard limits, as for example $$\frac{\tan (\pi x)}{\sin (ex)}$$ which is not solveble by simply trigonometric manipulations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When $\sin(3x)\ne0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\tan(6x)}{\sin(3x)}
&=\frac{\sin(6x)}{\cos(6x)\sin(3x)}\\
&=\frac{2\sin(3x)\cos(3x)}{\cos(6x)\sin(3x)}\\
&=2\frac{\cos(3x)}{\cos(6x)}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 5):

By standard limit $\frac{\sin t}{t}\to 1$ as $t\to 0$, we have

$$\frac{\tan(6x)}{\sin(3x)}=\frac{\tan(6x)}{6x}\frac{3x}{\sin(3x)}\frac{6x}{3x}\to 1\cdot 1\cdot 2=2$$

Answer (score 4):

With $\tan6x=\dfrac{2\tan3x}{1-\tan^23x}=\dfrac{2\sin3x}{\cos3x(1-\tan^23x)}$ then
$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\tan6x}{\sin3x}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{2}{\cos3x(1-\tan^23x)}=2$$

Answer (score 3):

For fun:

Note: $\tan 6x = \dfrac{2\tan 3x}{1-\tan^2 3x}$.

$\dfrac{1}{\cos 3 x}\dfrac {\tan 6x}{\tan 3x}=$

$\dfrac{1}{ \cos 3x} \dfrac{2}{1-\tan^2 3x}.$

The limit is?

Comment: @user108128 I know Peter very well, his solution is very similar to your but I don’t think it is intentional. The main idea is the same but the algebraic manipulation is slightly different

Comment: @user108128 I think you misunderstood what Peter meant

Comment: Gimusi.Thanks for your comment.User 108128's solution is quite  similar.  Have not looked at the answers thoroughly . Kind words from you:)))Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lim _{x\to 0} \frac {\tan 6x}{\sin 3x}  \\=    \lim _{x\to 0} \frac {\sin 6x}{\sin 3x\cos 6x}\\=\lim _{x\to 0} \frac {1} {\cos 6x} \lim _{x\to 0} \frac {\sin 6x}{\sin3x}\\ =\lim _{x\to 0} \frac {2\sin 3x \cos 3x}{\sin3x}= \lim _{x\to 0} {2 \cos 3x}  =2$$

Comment: @gimusi Thanks for the comment. I edited my solution.